# Rails: Param is missing or the value is empty in ManagerController#addtoproject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to add project_id and user_id to the following

```
 create_table "project_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Model project_user.rb

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :projects
end
```

This is my controller that is supposed to add data in the table:

```
def addtoproject
    @emp_id = params[:eid]
    @project_id = params[:pid]

    @add_user = ProjectUser.new(params.require(:projectuser).permit(:project_id, :user_id))
    @add_user.project_id = @project_id
    @add_user.user_id = @emp_id
    @add_user.save
  end
```

@emp_id and @project_id both contain valid values.
Rails is throwing the error on the line

```
@add_user = ProjectUser.new(params.require(:projectuser).permit(:project_id, :user_id))
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Any clues how this error can be fixed? As the table name is "project_users", I reckon I maybe missing an "_" somewhere?

**Update 1**
Clicking Add to Project invokes the method addtoproject inside controller.

[image]

addusers.html.erb:

```
<table id='employee-table' class="table table-hover">
    <thead  class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @employees.each_with_index do |employee, index| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= employee.id %></td>
          <td><%= employee.firstname + ' ' + employee.lastname %></td>
          <td><%= employee.user_type %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Add to Project", add_to_project_path(eid: employee, pid: @project_id), :class => "btn btn-success", :style => "float:right"%></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining because you're doing

```
params.require(:projectuser)
```

This means that `:projectuser` doesn't exist in `params`. You can see the parameters that are being sent to your controller further down in that screenshot. Only a `pid` and `eid` are present.

If you're using a `form`, you may need to change it to use something like [form_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) so your parameters are namespaced to the model.

```
<%= form_for @project_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :pid %>
  <%= f.number_field :eid %>
```

You'll also face errors with the `permit section since you specify

```
permit(:project_id, :user_id)
```

But the params passed are `pid` and `uid`. Use the name of your model fields in your inputs:

```
<%= form_for @project_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :project_id %>
  <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
```

Comment: I think I have not explained my situation propoerly. There is a simple table that has a button add to project, on clicking, it is supposed to pass the current project id and selected user id so that they can be saved in the table project_users. Can you please provide a modified statement that will help me in putting these two ids in the table project_users? I have added some more detail in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if the parameters are not passed using form_with as in my case, there is no need for params.require or params.permit (as quoted by @Cjmarkham these attributes are not present).

Just initialising an empty instance of the model and saving it worked for me.

```
@add_user = ProjectUser.new
@add_user.project_id = @project_id
@add_user.user_id = @emp_id
@add_user.save
```